# How to generate AES256 key in .net

Tags: java, .net, key-generator

I had Java Code which generate key AES256 Bit key, have to implement same Code in .Net

Here is my sample java

```
int SYMMETRIC_KEY_SIZE = 256;
public byte[] generateSessionKey() 
{
        //      KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES", JCE_PROVIDER);
        KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        kgen.init(this.SYMMETRIC_KEY_SIZE);
        SecretKey key = kgen.generateKey();
        byte[] symmKey = key.getEncoded();
        return symmKey;
    }
```

Below is my .net Code

```
public static string GenerateKey(int iKeySize)
        {
            RijndaelManaged aesEncryption = new RijndaelManaged();
            aesEncryption.KeySize = iKeySize;
            aesEncryption.BlockSize = 128;
            aesEncryption.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            aesEncryption.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            aesEncryption.GenerateIV();
            string ivStr = Convert.ToBase64String(aesEncryption.IV);
            aesEncryption.GenerateKey();
            string keyStr = Convert.ToBase64String(aesEncryption.Key);
            string completeKey = ivStr + "," + keyStr;

            return Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(completeKey));
        }
```

Above code generate key is "MnRpUVZmT3p5bG94R1RHYklMYU5Qdz09LDRZTUVQVlZWMHd0T2k3VGxEci9pejlBT3QvY215TFVNcFZ5ei93YnFuZk09"

I am getting key AES256 key from above code,which i had to convert it into bytes and pass at "skey" parameter in below function,but during execution of gcmb.Init(cipherOperation, ObjAeadParameters) i am getting error "invalid parameters passed to GCM".

GCM Block Cipher Encryption

```
public byte[] EncryptWithSessionKey(bool cipherOperation, byte[] skey, byte[] iv, byte[] aad, byte[] data)
            {
                try
                {
                    AeadParameters ObjAeadParameters = new AeadParameters(new Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters.KeyParameter(skey), AUTH_TAG_SIZE_BITS, iv,aad );
                    GcmBlockCipher gcmb = new GcmBlockCipher(new AesFastEngine());
                    gcmb.Init(cipherOperation, ObjAeadParameters);
                    byte[] result = new byte[gcmb.GetOutputSize(data.Length)];
                    int processLen = gcmb.ProcessBytes(data, 0, data.Length, result, 0);
                    gcmb.DoFinal(result, processLen);
                    return result;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    lobjlog.LogWrite("EncryptWithSessionKey Exception" + ex.InnerException.Message);
                    throw ex;
                }


            }
```

Comment: I suggest you using .net tag :)

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: I had shared above .net code which i am using at present, generated key is mismatched with java code key

Comment: I don't see the output of each, so I can't tell what is different.

Comment: These Both Code generate one  AES256 key which i had to pass it on  GCM BlockCipher Code as  AeadParameter , but i  there i am getting error . Here is my C# generated key S0JKbnBUSnh3b0Q5UDRVVEErZm5PcnA5WFlYNkM4SGJUN0poYW1ZbkliOD0= and  Gcm Error is "invalid parameters passed to GCM"

Comment: this is the key generated by .net Code "MnRpUVZmT3p5bG94R1RHYklMYU5Qdz09LDRZTUVQVlZWMHd0T2k3VGxEci9pejlBT3QvY215TFVNcFZ5ei93YnFuZk09"